# CSS responsive design: weird mobile scaling issue

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am making a very simple website which will implement two stylesheets: one for desktop users and one for mobile users.

While working on the mobile stylesheet, I have found wild inconsistencies that I cannot explain. The image below demonstrates the situation. On the left is the website viewed in Firefox's responsive design mode. On the right is the same website viewed in Firefox's Android mobile browser. The viewport is exactly the same in both views, I have checked and checked and triple checked. The browser's own window's resolution is the same in both the images.

[image]

As you can see, the mobile browser constantly uses some sort of scaling, that I cannot find reason for, for everything individually. The icons on the right panel of the footer are all a fixed size of 32px, and yet somehow they are scaled differently between the views. The stylesheet is the same for both views, and all the fonts are based on units of em, and yet even they are not in proportion to each other...

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What u probably need to do is change the viewport in the head of your website.

For instance `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5">`

When you put it like this it will turn up exactly like in the browser. When you change the viewport to 1 it will zoom in (double).

Comment: Viewport was, in fact, my issue. Thank you.